# Вывод элементов списка в таблицу Python

Tags: python, list

С помощью данного кода, вычисляю слова и их повторы в тексте:

```
from collections import Counter

word_list = []
for word in test1.split():
    clear_word = ""
    for letter in word:
        if letter.isalpha():
            clear_word += letter.lower()
    word_list.append(clear_word)

povtory = Counter(word_list)
```

Если выводить переменную povtory, то ее содержимое получается таким:

```
Counter({'скачать': 1, 'notepad': 1, 'для': 1, 'windows': 1, '': 1})
```

Как мне то что в кавычках вывести в один столбец, а то что после : в другой?

В таблицу вывожу следующим образом:

```
data = {
    'Слова': [povtory(элемент который в кавычках)],
    'Повторы': [povtory(элемент который после :)],
}
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
html_table = pretty_html_table.build_table(df, 'blue_light')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У словарей, чьим потомком является `Counter`, есть методы `keys` и `values`, которые возвращают последовательности ключей и значений:

```py
data = {
    'Слова': povtory.keys(),
    'Повторы': povtory.values(),
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, не знал этого!

Comment: @ToneR всегда пожалуйста 